# Why does WCF service give 401 error on IIS 6.0

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I have this wierd problem on our Windows Server 2003, XP box running IIS 6.0. I have a WCF service deployed using an application pool identity. I am able to browse the svc file like this on that box,

http://localhost/servicename.svc

But when I do http://machinename/servicename.svc, it asks for credentials. 
The website is configured for Anonymous access and Integrated Windows authentication.

I am really not sure what is wrong here, I have another machine that is a failover location for this box, where the same thing works fine with exactly same settings in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Application Pool identity has Read & Execute access on the files hosted by IIS (in other words, check the files at D:\path\to\site). Whether it's Network Service, a domain account, whatever.. it's going to need R&X permission.

What I'm guessing that's happening is that you're a local Admin on the server, so when you do it locally you're able to use your own local credentials to pull the site. But when you do it remotely, IIS must have access to these files - even if Anonymous access is enabled (otherwise, how can it load the files to serve the page to you?).

If you're still stumped, try using a program like filemon or procmon local on the server while making the request, and see what's getting Access Denied when you get a 401.